# How to save monitor on the left in extended screen mode?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

Generally, I switch from single screen to extended screen mode. However, every time I switch to extended, I need to change the position of the monitor "1" (my note) to the left (the default is the right).

Here comes the question: is there a way to save this layout, the "1" monitor is always on the left whenever I change the screen mode to extended in Ubuntu settings (or using Super + P)?

My Ubuntu is 20.04 LTS

Intel HD 620 is my graphics card

I'm a Linux novice!